# how to use apply on a list of text to loop through plots in r

Tags: r, loops, apply, lapply

I intended to generate multi-plot per page using something like this:

```
d=data.frame(label=c(rep('a',3),rep('b',3)) )
d$x = sample(6,nrow(d))
d$y = sample(10,nrow(d))

plotList <- lapply(c("a","b"), function(i) {
plot(df[i,2],df[i,3])
  })

  library(gridExtra)
  do.call(grid.arrange, c(plotList, nrow=2))
```

Intended effect is one point plot of label *a* data by the side ne point plot of label *b* data.  I know ggplot panel can work here

```
d %>% ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(.~label)
```

but the specific case I need to plot which i don't have a good way to share raw data here I'll need to use apply to plot it and grid.arrange to put on same page. I saw grid.arrange example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110929/several-hexbin-plots-on-one-pdf-page-in-r). Wondering how can i make apply function work? thanks

Comment: I don't really get what you need. could you give us more information or post the ggplot output which you say will work?

Comment: plots are not objects, unless you use other packages such as ggplot. so you can't put them in a list. But I'm not sure you need that anyway. also you use df instead of d, and df[i,2] instead of df[df$label == i,2]

Comment: If you really want to use the base graphics with `grid.arrange`, you will need the `gridGraphics` which allows you to redraw base graphics with `grid`.